# C - How to delete a certain string from a 2d array with position (New to Programming)

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and taking the course of BSIT, My teacher ask us to make a program relating to arrays, with the functions such as deleting, inserting/adding, updating.

The problem I encountered was with deleting. I know how to delete a certain element with position but that is only with arrays such as with int, but when it comes to char/string 2d array I don't really know how so if someone can provide a answer and a little bit of explanation it'll be a huge help. Thanks

**This is my code**:
[Just a sample]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    char brandName[20][20];

    int position = 2;

    //example just get 3 input for {"Nike", "Addidas", "Vans"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", brandName[i]);
    }


    //I want to delete the element in position 1 so it will be {"Nike", "Vans"}
    for(int i = position - 1; i < 3 - 1; i++)
    {
        brandName[i] = brandName[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `brandName[i] = brandName[i + 1];` ==> `strcpy(brandName[i], brandName[i + 1]);`. Not that for large arrays this can be performance inhibitive. If order retention isn't required an alternative is to just copy the *last* string over the one you want gone, then reduce your sequence length (stored somewhere) by 1. If order retention is mandetory you'll have little choice but to do what you're doing in some form or another.

Comment: @WhozCraig you mean something like {"Nike", "Vans", "Vans"} since copy the last one to the position where to delete?

Comment: More or less, yes, then decrement whatever far you're using that dictates how many "real" strings are in this array of arrays by 1. (hard to show, since you never used one in your code and instead have it sprinkled with magic number 3).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to move (shift) a built-in datatype like an `int` or a `double`.
 When it comes to "user defined datatypes" (like your 2D array, or an array of structs), you need `memmove()`.
 (NB: `memmove()` was written to **correctly** handle cases where the source and destination regions overlap. `memcpy()` will blow up in those cases.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 4 // For demo. You may want to use 20

int main() {
    // Initialise the first 4 elements of the array
    char names[ROWS][20] = { "Nike", "Adidas", "Vans", "Slazenger" };
    size_t i, sz = sizeof names/sizeof names[0];

    // Show content
    for(i=0; i<sz; i++) printf( "%zu - %s\n", i, names[i][0] ? names[i] : "empty" ); putchar('\n');

    // Erase one element
    int zap = 2; // aka index = 1;
    memmove( names[ zap - 1 ], names[ zap ], (sz - zap) * sizeof names[0] );

    // Show "invalid" content
    for(i=0; i<sz; i++) printf( "%zu - %s\n", i, names[i][0] ? names[i] : "empty" ); putchar('\n');

    // Erase the final slot whose content has been shifted "up"
    memset( names[sz - 1], 0, sizeof names[0] );

    // Show valid content
    for(i=0; i<sz; i++) printf( "%zu - %s\n", i, names[i][0] ? names[i] : "empty" ); putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

```
0 - Nike
1 - Adidas
2 - Vans
3 - Slazenger

0 - Nike
1 - Vans
2 - Slazenger
3 - Slazenger

0 - Nike
1 - Vans
2 - Slazenger
3 - empty
```

This keeps the "valid data" elements contiguous. Any code written to use this array will also want to keep track of the number of valid data elements.

An exercise is now to "shift" rows to open up a gap at the right location (perhaps to insert "records" in sorted order. Be sure to not try to push the final record (that will be lost) out of the region of memory allocated for your use.

PS: Yes, this would work for a simple array of `int`s, too... Or an array of structs...

---

**EDIT:**
Some may feel more comfortable with the following that implements a tiny "output" function that reveals the state of the array's records.

Seen this way, it becomes apparent that all that is needed are the two functions, `memmove()` and, optionally, `memcpy()` (if one want to zero-out the excess record(s) beyond the valid records.)

Care is needed as this is a wonderful place for an "off-by-one" bug to lurk. Careful testing is **strongly** advised.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void show( char *title, char arr[][20], size_t sz ) {
    puts( title );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
        printf( "%zu - %s\n", i, arr[i][0] ? arr[i] : "empty" );
    putchar('\n');
}

#define ROWS 4 // For demo. You may want to use 20

int main() {
    char names[ROWS][20] = { "Nike", "Adidas", "Vans", "Slazenger" };
    size_t sz = sizeof names/sizeof names[0];

show( "Original", names, sz );

    int zap = 2;
    memmove( names[ zap-1 ], names[ zap ], (sz - zap) * sizeof names[0] );

show( "Invalid", names, sz );

    // Erase the final slot that has been shifted "up"
    memset( names[sz - 1], 0, sizeof names[0] );

show( "Final", names, sz );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly suggest scoping `size_t i` locally to your for loops as it is not used outside of them and reset at the beginning of each loop. Also suggest moving `putchar('\n');` to a newline, as you lines right now are kind of long, and your current style may trick the inexperienced into thinking that is part of the loop.

Comment: @Chris Good points... However, 'i' is only used, as you note, for the loo-o-o-ng "debugging" print statements ( including the putchar() )... All intended as _demonstration code_, not that the output printf/putchar are anything more than that... The beginners are welcome to download the code and add whatever whitespace (newlines) they want to cast the code into something familiar... I even chose to leave the morass instead of making a "show()" function that might also cause controversy... All good. `:-)`

Comment: @Chris Variation posted... Thanks for your suggestion... Slow day here `:-)` (Although I do draw the line at strewing in a bunch of 'const' ... Living in the wild west `:-)`